# How can the decimal value of the sha256 hash be lower than one?

Tags: cryptography, bitcoin, mining

In bitcoin mining the sha256(sha256(blockheader)) hash has to be lower than 1/difficulty, right?. But how can a hex value be lower then 1. For example the hash of the genesis block is 000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f which is in decimal 10628944869218562084050143519444549580389464591454674019345556079 which is not lower than 1/1 which was the difficulty in the genesis block.

Comment: Maybe [this documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) will help you.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'lower than 1'.

Comment: Where did you read "1/difficulty"? I've never heard of that construction. Are you sure you haven't misread something? You're probably thinking "block1difficulty / difficulty" or something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.